# Render MS Symbol font characters in html5

Tags: html, fonts, ms-word, symbols, docx

I want to take characters in the Microsoft Symbol font (taken from the w:sym tag in a docx file) and render them in html.  When I look at how Word writes out the characters when I save the doc as html, I see this:

```
<span style='mso-char-type:symbol;mso-symbol-font-family:Symbol'>Â</span>
```

This appears as a script R in both Word and Word's html output.

When I write the same thing in my own html file, I see the A-hat in the regular font, and Chrome's element inspector warns that the mso- properties are unknown.

In Word's html output there is lots of mso-specific stuff but nothing I can see that lets Chrome know how to interpret mso-char-type and mso-symbol-font.  I see the same behavior in IE.

Is there an easy way to tell the browser to use the Symbol font?  Or do I have to explicitly translate the Symbol font characters to Unicode (using a static translation table?)

Thanks,

```
Wayne
```

Comment: Related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686414/extract-symbol-characters-from-docx

Answer (score 2):

The Symbol font is a privately-encoded font, i.e. it places various glyphs in positions that should be occupied by other characters according to character code standards. This means that a web page using it will fail badly whenever the Symbol font is not available, or the page style sheet is overriden, or the browser behaves correctly: e.g., the letter “Â” cannot be rendered using the Symbol font, so the browser will use a fallback font.

The proper way is to use Unicode encoded characters, such as “ℜ”, in a UTF-8 encoded page, with `font-family` on the applicable element set to contain a list of fonts that contain this character. For general notes on this, see my [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).

An inappropriate way that has worked on some faulty browsers is to set font to Symbol in a manner generally understood by browsers, e.g. `<font face=Symbol>Â</font>` or `<span style="font-family: Symbol">Â</span>`. But as said, if this “works”, consider it a browser bug.

So yes, if you now have data using Symbol font, it should be mapped to Unicode characters.

Note that characters like “ℜ” (Black-letter capital R, *not* script R) are seldom needed. In particular, the standard (as per ISO 80000-2) notation for the real part of a complex number *z* is not ℜ(*z*) but Re *z*.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  In my case I am taking these characters from existing word docx I have no control over, so the mapping will be needed.  Actually I am still wondering why the mso- attributes are recognized in Word's output but not mine...

Comment: Word 2007 produces, when saving as HTML (unfiltered): `<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-family:Symbol'>b<span style='mso-char-type:
symbol;mso-symbol-font-family:Symbol'><span style='mso-char-type:symbol;
mso-symbol-font-family:Symbol'>Â</span></span><o:p></o:p></span></p>`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just removing mso-symbol and writing font-family:Symbol seems to have worked.  However I suspect this is not really best practice...  A table for translating symbols into unicode can be found here: http://www.alanwood.net/demos/symbol.html

Comment: As the cited page says, “Symbol font should not be used in Web pages”. The Symbol font is trickery, and e.g. what search engines see is the characters you have on the page, not the Symbol font glyphs assigned to the characters.