# Extract symbol characters from docx

Tags: java, utf-8, openxml, symbols, docx

I'm developing a JAVA program  which processes the XML content of docx files and converts it to a specific format. It's working quite well, but I have problems if the Word file contains Symbol characters e.g. greek letters. In this case I see only little squares.

I checked the source and see something like this:

```
<w:r w:rsidRPr="008E65F6"><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Symbol" w:hAnsi="Symbol"/></w:rPr><w:t>ďˇ</w:t></w:r>
```

Or if I set the encoding to UTF-8:

```
<w:r w:rsidRPr="008E65F6"><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Symbol" w:hAnsi="Symbol"/></w:rPr><w:t></w:t></w:r>
```

When I view as Hexa, it seems that the greek characters are encoded as `EF 81 A1` for alpha, `EF 81 A2` for beta and so on.

I also tried `val.getBytes(Charset.forName("utf8"))` where val is the value of the `<w:t>` tag. The result is e.g. `[-17, -127, -95]`. The negative values are quite surprising for me.

So my question is, what is a safe and reliable way to covert these symbols to regular UTF-8 characters?

Comment: Typically, in a docx file emitted by Word, it is already UTF-8; see the XML declaration at the top of your main document part (/word/document.xml).  Is yours different?

Comment: Yes you are right, it's UTF-8. However, these characters are not displayed properly. Probably Symbol font does not use UTF-8 charcodes?

Comment: Hi Itamas...what happened to the application.....were you able to extract from docx ?

Comment: Hi @Raja ji, it was quite a long time. I wrote my solution in the answer below, that was sufficient for my goals. The main point was to recognize that the Symbol font uses special unicode character codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meanwhile, I have found the solution, so I add it as answer for future reference.

I checked the Symbol font with a glyph viewer software and I realized that it uses the Private Use Area of Unicode for its characters. Other fonts like Times New Roman store the concerned characters (e.g. greek letters) in normal Unicode range.

So the solution is to map the Symbol glyphs with standard Unicode glyphs. I have created a conversion table by hand for the greek letters (upper/lower case), punctuations, numbers and mathematical symbols available in the Symbol font. Note that even the order of the characters in variuos ranges differ from each other, e.g. the greek alphabet is not in the same order in Symbol and Unicode. So I had to check the character codes one by one.

When I had the conversion table, I stored it in a txt file. When my application finds a segment (run) in the Word file which is formatted with Symbol font (`<w:rFonts>` tag in the example), it calls the conversion method. In this method, I parse the txt file to a `HashMap`, and change the characters one by one from Symbol code to Unicode:

```
public String convert(String symbolString)  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int k=0; k<symbolString.length(); k++){
        int origCode = Character.codePointAt(symbolString, k);
        Integer replaceCode = conversionTable.get(origCode);
        if(replaceCode != null) {
            sb.append(Character.toChars(replaceCode));
        } else {
            sb.append("?");
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Where `conversionTable` is the `HashMap` object containing the replace codes as hex values.

Comment: Can you provide the conversion table?

Comment: Sorry, I see your commment just now, I hope it is not late yet. I saved the data in a txt file, and parse it from code. You can download my txt from here: http://goo.gl/eWh9BX . Note that it may not be complete, but the small and capital greek letters, the numbers and the most common mathematical signs are covered. It contains some hungarian language comments starting with #, you can ignore them. Do you need also the parsing code?

Comment: it seems the previous link is broken, here is an alternative: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B67SOq3A76N1R0FrRE13bEhSSWc/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-NAfTJgEI1fHo3653Uvkifg